# Converting Javascript Map function to Swift 2 Map function

Tags: javascript, swift

I am rewriting this question because my first one was quite vague. I am trying to conver the following javascript function using the map function into Swift 2.

Here is the javascript function.

```
function compute_correlations(timeseries, test_frequencies, sample_rate)
{
    // 2pi * frequency gives the appropriate period to sine.
    // timeseries index / sample_rate gives the appropriate time coordinate.
    var scale_factor = 2 * Math.PI / sample_rate;
    var amplitudes = test_frequencies.map
    (
        function(f)
        {
            var frequency = f.frequency;

            // Represent a complex number as a length-2 array [ real, imaginary ].
            var accumulator = [ 0, 0 ];
            for (var t = 0; t < timeseries.length; t++)
            {
                accumulator[0] += timeseries[t] * Math.cos(scale_factor * frequency * t);
                accumulator[1] += timeseries[t] * Math.sin(scale_factor * frequency * t);
            }

            return accumulator;
        }
    );

    return amplitudes;
}
```

And here is my Swift function. I am getting an error and am not even sure I am doing it correctly. Error is noted in the code.

```
func compute_correlations(timeseries:[Double], test_frequencies:[NoteInfo], sample_rate:Double) -> [Double]
    {
    // 2pi * frequency gives the appropriate period to sine.
    // timeseries index / sample_rate gives the appropriate time coordinate.
    let scale_factor = 2 * pi / sample_rate;
    let amplitudes: [Double]   = test_frequencies.map { f in

    let frequency = f.getFrequency()

    // Represent a complex number as a length-2 array [ real, imaginary ].
    var accumulator: [Double] = [ 0.0, 0.0 ]
    for (var t = 0; t < timeseries.count; t++)
    {
                accumulator[0] += timeseries[t] * cos(scale_factor * frequency * Double(t))
                accumulator[1] += timeseries[t] * sin(scale_factor * frequency * Double(t))
    }

    return accumulator  //ERROR  Cannot convert return expression of type '[Double]' to return type 'Double'

    }


    return amplitudes;
    }
```

And if needed here is the NoteInfo class

```
class NoteInfo {

    var frequency:Double!
    var note_name:String!
    init(theFrequency:Double, theNoteName:String){
        frequency = theFrequency
        note_name = theNoteName
    }

    func getFrequency()-> Double {
        return frequency
    }

    func getNoteName()-> String {
        return note_name
    }
}
```

Here is where I am populating the `test_frequencies`

```
 for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            let note_frequency = C2 * pow(2.0, Double(i) / 12.0)
            let note_name = notes[i % 12]
            let note = NoteInfo(theFrequency: note_frequency, theNoteName: note_name)
            test_frequencies.append(note)
        }
```

Comment: so what are you having problems with?

Comment: it sounds like `test_frequencies` is a collection of `Double.`

Comment: I will add the code where I am populating the test_frequencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your accumulator is a `[Double]`, and so the result of your `map` becomes `[[Double]]`. You then try to assign it to a `[Double]`.

You should either declare amplitudes accordingly:

```
let amplitudes: [[Double]]   = test_frequencies.map { f in
```

or (depending on your needs) return only one of the accumulator fields inside your `map`, e.g.

```
return accumulator[0]
```

Comment: Ah OK so amplitudes is an array of Doubles then, is what that syntax means?

Comment: That seems to have taken the error away. Now for the rest of the code... trying to make a guitar tuner so who knows how it will turn out, but this fixes the error so I am accepting as correct.